# Dismiss Context Actionbar when viewpager changes

Tags: android, contextual-action-bar

Right now I have an activity using a viewpager to display a several fragments. each of those fragments has implemented a Context Action Bar in the fragment. I am trying to make it where if the user scrolls or tabs between the fragments, the ActionBar for the previously selected fragment is dismissed.

I think I need to make some sort of call to the CAB `.finish()`in the fragment from my `OnPageChangeListener()` however I am not entirely sure how or where to do that.

Comment: Why? Does it have to reappear when you navigate back to that fragment?

Comment: no, I just want it to go away when I navigate away from that fragment.

Answer (score 1):

Create should a public function in each fragment which can be called to finish the ActionMode. Could look like this

```
public void finishActionMode(){
    [YOUR_ACTIONMODE_VARIABLE].finish();
}
```

Then in the activity you keep your ViewPager you should somehow keep or get a reference to the fragment in the ViewPager which should close its ActionMode, and then in your onPageSelected you can call `[YOUR_FRAGMENT_REFERENCE].finishActionMode();

Like this:

```
    mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            [YOUR_FRAGMENT_REFERENCE].finishActionMode();
        }

        ...
    });
```

For keeping a reference to a ViewPagers fragments look here: [Retrieve a Fragment from a ViewPager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785221/retrieve-a-fragment-from-a-viewpager)

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create individual **Contextual Action Bar(CAB)** for every fragments. You can simply create a single **STATIC** CAB in the TabbedActivity(Activity with pager) and use them anytime when needed.

Here is my code snippet of ***TabbedActivity.java***

```
public class TabbedActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

public static ActionMode uniActionMode=null;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int 
         positionOffsetPixels) {
          if(uniActionMode!=null)
             uniActionMode.finish();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position)
        {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

        }
    });

}
```

The `mViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener` is used to check if the user moves through the fragments. Now all you have to do is create an ActionMode from anywhere and then pass the value to the static `uniActionMode` variable.

```
mActionModeCallback = new ActionMode.Callback() {

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
            // Inflate a menu resource providing context menu items
            MenuInflater inflater = mode.getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_selection, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onPrepareActionMode(ActionMode mode, Menu menu) {
           return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onActionItemClicked(ActionMode mode, MenuItem item) {

            switch (item.getItemId()) {
                case R.id.action_delete:
                    mode.finish();
                    return true;

                case R.id.action_mark_read:

                    mode.finish();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroyActionMode(ActionMode mode) {

        }
    };

    TabbedActivity.uniActionMode=  v.startActionMode(mActionModeCallback);
```

Here the `TabbedActivity.uniActionMode` references the ActionMode Object of the Tabbed Activity. Thus the callbacks are passed to the `TabbedActivity.uniActionMode`.